# mysql rand() limit error

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a query like this:

```
$query = "select url from music where privacy=0 and musicid in (select musicid from tag where tagname in (select tagname from tag where musicid in (select musicid from music_like where userid=:userid  )) ) ***order by rand() limit 9,***" . $this->musicPerPage;
```

My problem is:

I known this query return 20 records

```
-- if write ***order by rand() limit 9*** -> no result

-- if write ***order by rand() limit 9,*** -> return 11 record

-- if write ***order by rand() limit 10,*** -> return 10 record

-- if write ***order by rand() limit 11,*** -> return 9 record
```

Someone can help me!

Comment: check what do you have under musicPerPage variable. If you have problem with any query, always dump it fully generated